# InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount optimal SpinCount (user mode)

Tags: c, windows, synchronization, critical-section

I don't quite understand the documentation for InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683476(v=vs.85).aspx

It says "You can improve performance significantly by choosing a small spin count ..."

However, since waiting on a spinner is faster than waiting for an object, doesn't it make sense to have the SpinCount as high as possible? What am I missing? Thanks.

(I am using it inside a C DLL used by a multi-threaded application)

Here is the code for the critical section, called constantly by a large number of threads:

```
int g_slots[256] = {0};
...
slot = 256;
EnterCriticalSection(&g_LockHandle);
while (slot-- > 0)
{
    if (g_slots[slot] == 0)
    {
        g_slots[slot] = spid;
        break;
    }
}
LeaveCriticalSection(&g_LockHandle);
```

---

Followup comments:

For anyone that is interested, here are my informal results when testing on a 4 core server running Windows 2008 R2: if doing an ultra-fast operation such as test and increment a single variable, Interlocked wins hands down. A distant second is CriticalSection+SpinCount with a low spin count (e.g., 16), followed by plain old CriticalSection. However, if scanning an array (e.g., of integers), Interlocked comes in third, after CriticalSection (with or without SpinCount). CriticalSection+high SpinCount was the slowest in all cases.

Neil Weicher
[www.netlib.com](http://www.netlib.com)

Comment: Regarding the code in your update, you can probably do that most efficiently lock free with CAS. But it all depends on exactly what the code is trying to achieve. We can only guess at that from the excerpt of code given here.

Comment: Spinwaits have to be tuned, you need a concurrency analyzer to arrive at the best value.  You can **not** blindly assume that spinning for a very long time is always better, even though it *looks* like the CS is only held for a very short time.  It will not be a short time once in a while when the thread that owns the CS loses the processor.  It won't come back for many milliseconds when the machine is loaded.  If you spinwait too long then you'll *decrease* efficiency because your spinning thread isn't giving the yielded thread an opportunity to regain the processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the documentation actually says, with my emphasis on the text that you removed, is:

> You can improve performance significantly by choosing a small spin count **for a critical section of short duration**.

So, the choice of spin count depends very critically on the duration of the critical section.

You ask:

> However, since waiting on a spinner is faster than waiting for an object, doesn't it make sense to have the SpinCount as high as possible?

It is simply not true that spinning is faster than blocking. For a long duration critical section, it is best to avoid spinning altogether. If it is likely that the lock won't be released for a significant amount of time, then the best policy is to block immediately and wait until you can acquire the lock. Even for a short duration section, it is possible that the thread that holds the lock is not scheduled to run, in which case spinning is clearly wasteful of CPU resource.

Spinning is only beneficial if there is a good probability that the lock can be acquired whilst spinning. And even then only if the time spent spinning is less than the time spent yielding, the context switch cost.

Comment: Yes, this is a critical section of very short duration that is constantly executed by multiple threads. How does the spin count affect performance one way or the other? Assuming a very short critical section, what is the disadvantage of a high spin count?

Comment: I think that's covered in the final two paragraphs. If you spin for a long time you are consuming CPU resources in a wasteful way. The processor could be doing something useful instead. The fact that the section is short doesn't mean that it will always end quickly. The thread that has the lock may not be running when another thread requests the lock.

Comment: I added the code for the critical section above. Would that call for a high or low spin count? Are you saying that while any thread is spinning, no other threads are running?

Comment: @Neilw *Are you saying that while any thread is spinning, no other threads are running?* No, I'm not saying that at all. I'm saying that a thread can hold a lock, and not be running. In which case spinning on the lock is pointless. It just delays the thread that has the lock getting scheduled to run again. All the time your thread is spinning, that is wasted CPU. For the code in your question, I suspect a lock free approach would be best.

Comment: Why lock-free? With a sufficient number of threads there is a good possibility of two threads getting the same slot.

Comment: I mean lock free synchronisation. CAS for example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: I think that what you don't seem to understand is that any time you are spinning you are stopping the CPU being used to make forward progress. Spinning can be useful to avoid the cost of context switches, but you must not ever spin as long as it takes to perform a context switch.

Comment: You mean with InterlockedCompareExchange? Do you think that will be a faster mechanism in this case? Maybe I will try to do a performance comparison. Also, do you have a recommendation for a spin count in the above code?

Comment: @Neilw It's hard to give a recommendation for the spin count. You'd need to benchmark carefully. Could depend on all sorts of factors. Type of hardware, number of processors, number of threads, frequency of acquiring the lock, what else runs on the machine. It's not realistic to expect good perf optimisation advice from people that don't even know what your program is doing. What profiling have you done so far?

Comment: I'm going to compare the three methodologies (InterlockedCompareExchange, InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount, and InitializeCriticalSection) and will post some numbers.

Comment: Ok this is what I found on a 4-core Win2008R2 machine: if doing an ultra-fast operation such as test and increment a single variable, Interlocked wins hands down. A distant second is CriticalSection+SpinCount with a low spin count (e.g., 16), followed by plain old CriticalSection.  However, if scanning an array (e.g., of integers), Interlocked comes in third, after CriticalSection (with or without SpinCount). Let me know if you'd like to see the numbers. CriticalSection+high SpinCount was the slowest in all cases.

Comment: Do you need any more help here?

Comment: No was just presenting my findings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to the statement "You can improve performance significantly by choosing a small spin count" itself.

When I tested my object pool class which uses InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount on a 8-core PC, the best value was lesser than 20. The larger spin count is, the slower it works.

These are my deduction by this test result:

- The smaller spin count is, the lesser meaningless processing is consumed.
- Very small spin count works well for routines where O(1) is guaranteed (e.g. no loop)

I don't think spin count should be larger than thousands. Spin count is a busy-wait. It not only consumes CPU power, but also consumes much bandwidth between CPU and RAM, thus it may  cause starvation of traffic between other CPUs and RAM.

Comment: Thanks - my findings concur with yours: very low spin count. The surprise for me was that for a table lookup, Critical Sections performed better than InterlockedCompareExchange for anything other than a very small table.